# Django docs Polls App, Different queryset returns same object values but QuestionIndexViewTests works for one query and fails for other

Tags: python, django

In polls application I added annotation to check one to many relationship between Question and Choice models such that, Index only return questions with more than one choices to be displayed but my testcase fails all the time with annotation where both query returns same data.

views.py(Working)

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'polls/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

views.py(Not Working: Added .annotate(num = Count('choice')).filter(num__gt=1))

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'polls/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects.annotate(num = Count('choice')).filter(num__gt=1).filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

tests.py

```
class QuestionIndexViewTests(TestCase):
def test_no_questions(self):
    """
    If no questions exist, an appropriate message is displayed.
    """
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

def test_past_question(self):
    """
    Questions with a pub_date in the past are displayed on the
    index page.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Past question.>']
    )

def test_future_question(self):
    """
    Questions with a pub_date in the future aren't displayed on
    the index page.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

def test_future_question_and_past_question(self):
    """
    Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
    are displayed.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
    create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Past question.>']
    )

def test_two_past_questions(self):
    """
    The questions index page may display multiple questions.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
    create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
    )
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hmnsh\repos\DjangoApp\mysite\polls\tests.py", line 80, in test_past_question
    ['<Question: Past question.>']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 940, in assertQuerysetEqual
    return self.assertEqual(list(items), values, msg=msg)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ['<Question: Past question.>']
```

Comment: In which test is line 940 ??

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo that refers to Django package: django\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 940